# Concatenate URL in bash with xargs

Tags: bash, xargs

I'm trying to build URLs from output with one entry per line. I have tried this:

```
<stuff> | xargs -L1 -I {} echo "${url}&page=queryresults&j="{}
```

However, for some long lines (they don't have space but can have dashes and underscores), I get '{}' where I would expect the string that's generated by `<stuff>`. If I add a space between the final double quote and {} it works, but I have an extra space I don't want:

```
<stuff> | xargs -L1 -I {} echo "${url}&page=queryresults&j=" {}
```

Similarly, if I remove the `&page=queryresults` bit, it works. I have no idea why.

What am I missing here?

It works for this:

```
blajob_123abcd_1234567890x
```

But not this: `SomeTask_some_long_project_name_with_cumulative_metrics_YYYYMMDD_2018_08_15T00_12345a67b8-scheduled-run-bla-bla-bla-yadda`

Comment: Could you show a sample input/output for the cases where it work and when it doesn't ?

Comment: Edited with example

Comment: Try: `xargs -I {} printf "$url&page=queryresults&j=%s\n" '{}'`

Comment: Which bash version?  The first version (no space) works fine for me on both testcases you gave with `bash 4.4.12(3)-release`.  Nevertheless, I agree with the comment from @anubhava - it is more robust against special-to-bash characters in the URLs.

Comment: Your examples both work for me.

Comment: @anubhava, why use `-I` at all in that case? `xargs printf "$url&page=queryresults&j=%s\n"` is more efficient, since you reuse a single `printf` for as many invocations as possible.

Comment: ...the problem, though, is we don't know what's in `$url` and whether it contains backslashes or `%` literals.

Comment: @cxw, ...in general, I agree that `printf` is more robust than `echo`, but I disagree that that's true for `printf "${url}..."`; there's a reason using parameter substitutions in the format string is an antipattern unless done with care.

Comment: Can we assume the input is also already properly URL-encoded?

Comment: If so, we'd definitely need to expect literal `%`s. Granted, `${url//%/%%}` is a mitigation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need for `xargs` here at all, and you're better off without it. The following is guaranteed to work correctly on all POSIX-compliant shells:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf '%s&page=queryresults&j=%s\n' "$url" "$line"
done
```

Why not stick with `xargs -I {} echo "$url&...&j={}"`?

- `xargs -I`'s specification includes the following text: **Constructed arguments cannot grow larger than 255 bytes**. If your URL is long, this could result in truncation -- which appears to match with the details described.
- `xargs -I` is only included in XSI extensions to POSIX; platforms which do not claim to implement those extensions are not required to provide it, or if they do, to have it behave in any particular way.
- If you used `xargs printf "$url..."` (substituting the URL into the format string rather than through a placeholder), you would have bugs if your URL contained `%` signs.
- If you used `echo`, you would have unspecified behavior if your URL contained literal backslashes (see the APPLICATION USAGE section of [the POSIX specification for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html)).

---

That said, if you **really** want to use `xargs`, consider (on GNU systems):

```
xargs -d $'\n' printf "${url//%/%%}"'&page=queryresults&j=%s\n'
```

...or, on a platform with BSD tools:

```
tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 printf "${url//%/%%}"'&page=queryresults&j=%s\n'
```

Note:

- Because we aren't using `-I`, the 255 character limit doesn't apply at all. (Similarly, `xargs` is able to pass as many arguments to each instance of `/usr/bin/printf` as will fit onto its command line, rather than being limited to one argument per call).
- In the URL, we replace any `%` literals with `%%`. If the URL is already correctly encoded, it shouldn't contain any backslashes (they should already have been replaced with `%5C`).
- The GNU extension `-d` is being used to specify that only newlines should be treated as delimiters between words to be treated as arguments; this also prevents literal quotes from being parsed and consumed by `xargs` itself. On BSD platforms, converting newlines to NULs and using `-0` serves as a substitute.

Comment: What could be the alternative of `xargs -d` on macOS/BSD?

Comment: `tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0`; edited the answer appropriately.